# How to get an xml value from an API

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I'm trying to display some value that is incorporated in an API (This api is used by a program called PRTG to extract information from the program), this is the API

> http://192.168.1.65/api/table.xml?content=channels&output=xml&columns=name%2Clastvalue_&id=1234&username=someguy&password=notmypassword

this API give's you an xml file that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<channels totalcount="0" listend="1">
    <prtg-version>16.4.27.6720</prtg-version>
    <item>
        <name>Tiempo de inactividad</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Voltaje Bateria</name>
        <lastvalue>54,51 VDC</lastvalue>
        <lastvalue_raw>0000000000054510.0000</lastvalue_raw>
    </item>
</channels>
```

I want to take the value in the tag **lastvalue** and display it in a webpage, I have tried using javascript but nothing works at all

Comment: Is it a question related to java, javascript or jquery. Please make it more clear

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the code you've tried, and tell what that code did that wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: I have tried using javascript, using requestAjax.

Comment: I can not add all the code that I've tried is too long, I'm new in stackoverflow btw

Comment: Atleast show some code you tried so we can figure out whether this is a java or javascript question hehe.

Comment: Just to clarify, *Java* is to *JavaScript* like *water* is to *watermelon*. That is, they are totally unrelated things. Hence everyone's confusion with the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need JavaScript because result should display on the page. If you calling API just change that ajax part and everything should work. To mimic some response from API I have done this over the file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="result"></p>

    <script>
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "channels.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();

    function myFunction(xml) {
        var x, i, txt, xmlDoc, node; 
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        txt = "";
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
            node = x[i].getElementsByTagName('lastvalue');
            if (node && node.length > 0){
                txt += node[0].textContent + "<br>";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = txt;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
 </html>
```

[image]